# Slow Fulcrum indexing

Tags: synchronization

I write here because I haven't found any other notions about it on the web and it's been 10 days since my node running fulcrum has indexed the synchronized blocks at a low speed (~14.3 blocks/min) at a height of 581000 (~ 71.3%). Talking to a friend with same hardware **(1.6GHz GX-217GA CPU, 4GB RAM)** it took him about 5 days... What can I do, do you have any ideas? Would it make sense to move to a higher performing machine for indexing and then switch back to the lower performing machine?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using an HDD or is your hard drive connected via USB?

Comment: @Murch I am using a SSD over SATA... I think that I only have to wait

Comment: Same here. 10 days so far to get to 65%...